# Database location for a paper to be indexed by google scholar

Tags: google-scholar, indexing, web-of-science

In some fields like architecture and design, repositories are setup for collecting the conference proceedings in one location.  Unfortunately these repositories are not always parsed well by google scholar.  Recently, the largest database in architecture began working with web of science conference proceedings database.  It seems that even with this, google scholar has not found these papers.  Are there examples of papers being indexed from the conference proceedings, or should we be looking for alternative repository methods.

Comment: I'm pretty sure google scholar is not getting the data from web of science. The publishers can work together with google to have those listed. And I can only speak about chemistry (where a conference proceeding is basically worth nothing) and here you will find proceedings most likely only if they were published within a journal which is listed on google scholar.

Comment: Google provide guidelines on how to be included, e.g., https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html

Comment: Google Scholar just crawls the web. As Web of Science requires a login, it is not indexed by Google Scholar ([source](https://scholar.google.de/intl/de/scholar/help.html#coverage)): "Nor do we include websites that require you to sign up for an account". Repositories are included, if they provide data in the way Google Scholar describes on the help page.